# SAS connect to SQL Server and return parameter

Tags: sql-server, sas

I want so save return value from a SQL Server stored procedure in a SAS variable.

Here is my code:

```
proc sql;
Connect To OLEDB As MyDb ( Init_String = "  Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; ... )

    Execute (spDamjanTest) by MyDb;

    Disconnect From MyDb;
Quit;
```

If I use code below, the stored procedure is executed twice:

```
     proc sql; 
            connect to oledb as SQLSVR (provider=sqloledb
            properties=("Data Source"=...);
            select *
            from connection to SQLSVR
            (exec spDamjanTest);
            disconnect from SQLSVR;
    quit;
```

Stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE spDamjanTest
  AS
  Select 5
```

Comment: i am not sure whether SAS can read through dbms stored procedure

Comment: Please show stored procedure to see if it returns a resultset or uses parameters. And can't see how second block runs stored proc twice.

Comment: Your stored procedure does not seem to be making a table. What variable name do you want it to assign to the value `5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table output (lets call it a result set) of a SQL Server stored procedure can be captured by `insert`ing it into a temporary table.  Once the result set is in a temporary (`#<table-name>`) table you can select from it from SAS.

```
* libname SS sqlsvr ... ;

proc sql;
  connect using SS;

  execute (
    create table #sp_table_out (
      column1 int
    )
    insert into #sp_table_out exec dbo.spDamjanTest
  ) by SS;

  create table work.sp_output as
  select * from connection to SS
  (
    select * from #sp_table_out 
  );

  execute (
    drop table #sp_table_out
  ) by SS;
quit;

proc print data=work.sp_output;
run;
```

This answer based on information from [How to Get the Output of a Stored Procedure into a Table](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/how-to-get-the-output-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-table.html) Greg Larsen, November 2016

Answer (score 0):

This is what the docs for 9.3 say:

> Any return code or message that is generated by the DBMS is available
>   in the macro variables SQLXRC and SQLXMSG after the statement
>   executes. See Macro Variables for Relational Databases for more
>   information about these macro variables.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/65247/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0pj5uu3i328pmn1fackclh2xnd9.htm

Have you tried that? What happened?

Comment: I think it looks like he wants to have return value from stored procedure not the return code

Comment: The page linked above says that PROC SQL doesn't support return parameters, so I guess it's just not possible.

Comment: @Chris It returns return code, not data from stored procedure thx for your help